# Using .htaccess rewrites to redirect from old url to new url

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a website `example.com` which was the old domain name for my site. We wish to switch from the old domain name to a new domain name `theexample.com`.

As the site is hosted using a web host we currently have both domain names pointing to the same ip address. I thought that I should be able to put a .htaccess file in the server's root directory which would redirect from the old site to the new site based on a rewritecond. I was the thinking the code below would do the trick but it doesn't work

```
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^example.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://theexample.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Comment: What do you mean about, *"it is of no use"*? Is your code workin'?

Comment: How does this question not relate to programming? It is a .htaccess file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay.. The code in your question seems right! However, you can still try these configuration directives in your *.htaccess* file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://theexample.com/$1
```

But first, make sure that there's an **Apache HTTP Server** with `mod_rewrite` in your web host.